# GLES and noperspective

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I'm rendering a number of triangles provided in clip coordinates with OpenGL ES 3.0. Using a varying, I generate interpolated texture coordinates for every fragment. However, since the interpolation uses the z coordinate of the vertices the interpolation is not linear in screen space. GLES, as far as I know, does not support the noperspective qualifier which supposedly does what I want.

Do you have a recommendation for a workaround? I could supply the clip coordinates without z, but I need z for depth testing.

Answer (score 2):

I believe in your case you can fix the depth in the fragment shader (supported in ES3). You could use that to set the depth while removing the `Z` coordinate from the position. You would need another varying value for the `Z` component though.

So in fragment shader you would have something like:

```
...
varying zPositionComponent;
...
    vac4 actualVertexPosition = ...; // whatever you had in gl_Position
    zPositionComponent = actualVertexPosition.z;
    gl_Position = vec4(actualVertexPosition.x, actualVertexPosition.y, 0.0, actualVertexPosition.w);
```

then in fragment shader simply add the fragment depth correction as `gl_FragDepth = zPositionComponent;`

**Note:** I am not sure this will work or if you actually have the support for this. You might actually need to check the current depth at the fragment and discard the fragment (manually doing the depth buffer) which can complicate things... Let me know how it goes and leave the question unanswered to see some better solutions please.

Comment: According to this https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test the depth test will use gl_fragdepth, but it will eliminate early depth test which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Yes well that is what I meant with a manual depth buffer test. It gets complicated. Still there might not be a better solution... You could I guess write the shape "IDs" to stencil buffer with depth buffer and then redraw them without the Z coordinate but that sounds even worse.. Maybe if you added some more info on what exactly you are doing.

Comment: Basically I'm drawing a number of billboards / 2D quads, but the geometry shall still have correct z-Testing with the rest of the scene.

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL uses w component of position to correct the perspective. See equation 13.7 of this [specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.1/es_spec_3.1.pdf) for details.

```
attribute vec2 a_uv;
varying vec3 v_uv;

vec4 pos = MVP * vertex;
gl_Position = pos;
v_uv = vec3(a_uv * pos.w, pos.w);
```

then in fragment shader:

```
vec2 uv = v_uv.xy / v_uv.z;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me is to do the persperpective divide yourself in the **vertex shader**:

```
gl_Position = MVP * vertex;
gl_Position /= gl_Position.w;
```

To me this is the most obvious solution, but the fact that nobody mentioned it before makes me think I might be missing something. Anyways, I have tested this myself and the results seem to be identical to using 'noperspective'.

Comment: The only problem with this approach is with big triangles where all the vertices are outside of the frustum volume but the triangle is visible, then this technique can generate vertex artifacts